# Is America the Beautiful Pass sold at Cabrillo National Monument?

Tags: usa, tickets, california, national-parks, san-diego

Here is a [list of federal recreational areas where interagency passes are issued](https://store.usgs.gov/s3fs-public/PassIssuanceList.pdf). It mentions Cabrillo National Monument. Here's a picture of [Cabrillo National Monument Fee Station](https://goo.gl/maps/gq4TWzk8nsARMzQ8A) from Google Maps:

[image]

The signs only mention the $20 per car fee, and there is no mention of America the Beautiful Annual Pass.

Can I nevertheless purchase the annual pass at this location? Or are they sold somewhere in a separate location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can buy the pass there, but [only until 4:20 pm each day](https://www.nps.gov/cabr/planyourvisit/basicinfo.htm).

Perhaps 50 feet ahead of the entrance station is a sign showing all of the available fees and passes. The [Interagency Annual Pass](https://www.nps.gov/planyourvisit/passes.htm) (the official name for this pass) is listed, along with the other variants (senior, military, access pass, etc).

[image: Cabrillo National Monument fees and passes sign]